# Disable emojis in dotnet watch run

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-cli

I upgraded to .NET SDK 6.0.300. When running `dotnet watch run`, the logs show emojis.

How do I disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch?view=aspnetcore-6.0#non-ascii-characters) is this environment variable:

```sh
DOTNET_WATCH_SUPPRESS_EMOJIS=1
```

Example: from the shell:

```sh
DOTNET_WATCH_SUPPRESS_EMOJIS=1 dotnet watch run
```

Example: in vscode's `tasks.json`:

```
{
    "label": "watch",
    "type": "process",
    "command": "dotnet",
    "args": [
        "watch",
        "run"
    ],
    "options": {
        "env": {
            "DOTNET_WATCH_SUPPRESS_EMOJIS": "1"            // <--------
        }
    },
    "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
}
```